# Select2 values are shown, but is actually empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple"
    name="regular[]" id="regular" multiple="multiple" required>
    <option value="History">History</option>
    <option value="Political Science">Political Science
    </option>
    <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
    <option value="Education">Education</option>
    <option value="Philosophy">Philosophy</option>
    <option value="Elective Assamese">Elective Assamese
    </option>
    <option value="Elective Hindi">Elective Hindi</option>
    <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
    <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="Linguistics">Linguistics</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is my select2 input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#regular').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select any two from the options',
        maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    });
});
```

I've loaded the select2.js here. and I am fetching data from ajax call.

`options = data.regular.split(",");`

this `option` has 3 values, I want to select the first two from the array.
Hence My code is..

```
option = [options[0],options[1]];
$("#regular").val(option).trigger('change');
```

Now the options are showing in the list. But if I click and select from the input, everything resets and I have to select again. And if without changing anything I want to submit, the field shows required.

Comment: what's your data from server look like

Comment: `$("#regular").val([options[0],options[1]]).trigger('change');` You can give comma seperated values in an array. for example `$("#regular").val([1,2]).trigger('change');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the code works  because the values from the server  are identical to two of the values of the Option elements

So maybe your problem is the option string is not already existing

,  Also it's case sensitive   so   "arabic" !==  "Arabic"   arabic will not work

either change in option tag  or change the value string from JSON response

Hope this Helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  mySelect = $('#regular').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select any two from the options',
    maximumSelectionLength: 2
  });

  options = 'Economics,Arabic,Education'.split(',');
  option = [options[0],options[1]];

  //simulate ajax using timeout
  setTimeout(function() {
    mySelect.val(option).trigger("change");
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" name="regular[]" id="regular" multiple="multiple" required>
    <option value="History">History</option>
    <option value="Political Science">Political Science
    </option>
    <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
    <option value="Education">Education</option>
    <option value="Philosophy">Philosophy</option>
    <option value="Elective Assamese">Elective Assamese
    </option>
    <option value="Elective Hindi">Elective Hindi</option>
    <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
    <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="Linguistics">Linguistics</option>
  </select>
</div>
```